# Testing search flight ticket web-form using splinter

Tags: python, search, webforms, splinter

Im' testing ticket search form on http://www.go2see.ru trying to get access to it elements: button, fields.
I need to fill 2-nd text field "Destination". 
I using following code and got following exception:

```
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser()

# Fill in the url
browser.visit('http://www.go2see.ru')

#find and fill 2-nd text field (Destination), right of two air planes 
browser.find_by_id('avia-to').first.find_by_tag('input').fill('Moscow') 

File "/home/ada015/search_form_testing.py", line 9, in <module>
  browser.find_by_id('avia-to').first.find_by_tag('input').fill('Moscow')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 75, in __getattr__
  self.__class__.__name__, name))

AttributeError: 'ElementList' object has no attribute 'fill'
```

Comment: `find_by_tag('input')` returns a list of elements, not a single element. You probably need to use `find_by_tag('input').first.fill`

Comment: @Lukas Graf
I tried:
`browser.find_by_id('avia-to').first.find_by_tag("input").first.fill('Moscow')`
Have error:

`splinter.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found with tag "input"`

I also checked html, it looks like:
`<input type="text" name="section[0].to.modified" id="avia-to" value="" class="toInput DirectionAutoComplete ui-autocomplete-input valid" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">`